# Invertible matrices property

Tags: matrices

I'm wondering about this property :

$\forall A \ \in \ \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ if there is $k \ \in \ \mathbb{N}^{*}$ such as $A^k=I_n$ then $A$ is invertible.

I think this assertion is true I do not find counter-examples but I do not see how to proove it. Would you have an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: This is obvious since $AA^{k-1}= A^{k-1}A=I_n$ , so that the inverse is exactly $A^{k-1}$.

Comment: This claim can easily be proven by induction, it's actually a special case of a similar result for groups.

Answer (score 4):

For matrices with your property, $AA^{k-1}=A^{k-1}A=I$