# Is the identity matrix the only matrix which is its own inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I just gave a proof for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184266/invertible-matrices-property/1184367#1184367). Here's my follow up question: Let $A \in \ \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{F})$ where F is a field and there exists $n\in N$  where $A^n$= I. In the case where n=1,2, $A^1$=I and $A^2$=I.

Here's my question: In general, if A is it's own inverse, then does it necessarily follow A=I? In other words, is I the only matrix which is it's own inverse? My gut reaction is to say no, but it would probably be fairly tedious to construct a matrix multiplication formula which produces the subset $S\subset \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ where S = {A | AA =I }. Is there such a subset in general? We know the set's nonempty since $I\in S$. Are there any others?

Comment: Is $1$ the only number which is its own inverse?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first paragraph. What's wrong with $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito MULTIPLICATIVE inverse in the field of real numbers,yes. But these are matrices and don't follow the same algebraic structures in general.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234:  There's another element in the field of real numbers which is its own inverse.  Using that, you can easily build many examples of matrices which are their own inverses.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 If you have a field, you have a multiplication, a $1$ and a $-1$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Correct, 1 and -1 both are thier own multiplicative inverses by definition, my bad.I have a bad habit of only considering positive numbers unless it's pointed out to me.

Comment: @GitGud See my response to Jason.

Comment: Rotation by 180 degrees is its own inverse...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for [involutory matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix). To answer the question: no, there are other matrices that are their own inverses.

Answer (score 13):

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ \sin\theta &-\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ \sin\theta &-\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$
for any $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: any reflection matrix $\pmatrix{\cos t & \sin t\\\sin t & -\cos t}$ would do.

Comment: you are welcome.

Comment: *facepalm* Right in front of my face and didn't see it.

Answer (score 8):

If $A^2=I$, then $(A-I)(A+I)=0$. Suppose that $J$ is the [Jordan Canonical Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of $A$, then since $A=SJS^{-1}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=S^{-1}(A^2-I)S\\
&=S^{-1}AAS-S^{-1}IS\\
&=S^{-1}ASS^{-1}AS-I\\
&=J^2-I
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $J$ must be a diagonal matrix all of whose diagonal elements are $+1$ and $-1$.

Therefore, $A^2=I$ if and only if $A$ is [diagonalizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) and has [eigenvalues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) $+1$ and $-1$.

Easy examples are diagonal matrices whose diagonal elements are $+1$ and $-1$, but any [similar matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) will also work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can actually create examples of such matrices very easily. All you need is a linear transformation which is it's own inverse. Just choose a basis and swap some extries (make sure to do disjoint swaps), for example, say $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, such that $T(e_1) = e_2, T(e_2) = e_1$, the corresponding matrix will be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with $1$s in bottom left and top right entries and zeroes elsewhere.

A harder question would be does there exist a basis with respect to which this linear transformation is a diagonal matrix all of whose diagonal elements are $+1$ and $−1$. The answer is yes, since then such a involutory matrix has eigenvalues $+1$ and $-1$.