# $T^2=I$ implies $T$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T:V\rightarrow V$ is linear and $T^2=I$. Prove that $T$ is diagonalizable.

First, I know that $T$ has only eigenvalues 1 or -1. Also I observed that $(T-I)(T+I)=0$, does this fact help to show that $T$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: Yes it does. Do you know about minimal polynomials?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Not really. I will try john's method and see if it works.

Comment: From Jordan form it follows immediately $ PJP^{-1} PJP^{-1}=I $,Squarred Jordan block is identity only if it is diagonal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you can split $V = V_1 \oplus V_{-1}$ where $T$ acts as either $1$ or $-1$.  Then take the direct sum over each subspace. $T = T_1 \oplus T_{-1}$

---

Since $T^2 v = v$ for all $v \in \mathbb{V}$ (an [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics))), we can decompose every vector as:

$$ v = \underbrace{\tfrac{1}{2}(v + Tv)}_{E_1} + 
\underbrace{\tfrac{1}{2}(v - Tv)}_{E_{-1}},$$

where $E_\lambda$ is an eigenspace with eigenvalue $\lambda$, so this eigenspace decomposition exists for all vector.

Comment: how do I know that $V$ is the sum of the eigenspaces? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since the minimum polynomial factors over the field into distinct linear factors this implies that $T$ is diagonalisable.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1184948), the Jordan Canonical Form of $A$ is a diagonal matrix with only $+1$ or $-1$ along the diagonal. That is, $A=SDS^{-1}$ where $D$ a diagonal matrix where each element on the diagonal is $+1$ or $-1$. Thus, $A$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposition is in general false unless you specify which elements the matrices are allowed to take.

The matrix $T = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$ with elements in non-negative reals or integers has $T^2 = I$ without being diagonalizable.

This particular T gives $aT$ for positive real a is a representation for negative reals if $aI$ represent positive a. Furthermore if we define addition as the subspace spanned by all matrices except $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&1\\1&1\end{array}\right)$ we can perform both addition and multiplication - we have constructed new numbers!

Example, add 2 and -1: Just ordinary matrix addition: $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2&1\\1&2\end{array}\right)$, but after stripping the projection on $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&1\\1&1\end{array}\right)$, we are left with $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)$ which represents 1.

Comment: Aren't $\{(1,1), (1,-1)\}$ eigenvectors?

Comment: Not if -1 is not allowed as an element.

Comment: Which field?  Non-negative reals $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ are **not** a field, since $1$ does not have an additive inverse.  $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field since $\frac{1}{2} \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes you are right, it's not a field. Let's just say the set of elements is limited to positive reals.

Comment: If we use $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ we get a [$\mathbb{Z}$-module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form).  In the other case, $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is not even a group, so  [non-negative matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_matrix) are a world of their own.

Comment: Is there even a theory of diagonalisation for matrices over semirings?