# If $A^4 = I$ (Identity Matrix) Then $A^2 = \pm I$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $A^4 = I$ (Identity Matrix), is then $A^2 = \pm I$?

I believe the statement is true by doing a few examples, but I am struggling to start my proof. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is not for all ring having zero divisors I believe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've done too few examples.
If you allow complex entries, consider $$ A=\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},$$
if not, consider
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your question can be put more simply, by defining $B=A^2$, as: does $B^2=I$ imply $B=\pm I$?

And the answer is not. Consider first that $B^2=I \iff B=B^{-1}$.  Then, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184490/is-the-identity-matrix-the-only-matrix-which-is-its-own-inverse).

As pointed out in an [aswer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1184948/312), the necessary and sufficient condition is to have $B$ diagonalizable and with eigenvalues $\pm 1$ [*]

[*] Edit: As per David C. Ullrich's comment, strictly speaking we need an additional restriction: that $B$ has a square root, that is, there exists some $A$ such that $A^2=B$. That's automatically true for complex matrices, but not so for real matrices (or some other fields). For example, both $B=\begin{pmatrix}1 &0\\0 &-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=-I$  verify the $B^2=I$ condition, but 
they don't have square root in the reals.

Given that, in the question, you seem to accept the alternative $A^2=-I$, suggests that you are dealing with the complex field, but this needs to be pointed out.

Comment: Your simpler version is not equivalent unless we know somehow that every matrix is the square of some matrix. Which is not true (at least not over an arbitrary field).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Because the OP accepts $A^2=-I$, I assumed we were dealing with the complex field, but you are right. Clarified.